# How to filter pandas data frame by subgroups with a condition in another column value

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am struggling finding a solution, here is the problem.

I have a dataframe of the form:

```
date         day_time   day_time_counter  area

2019-06-05   morning    1                 1
2019-06-05   morning    1                 2
2019-06-05   morning    1                 3

2019-06-05   morning    2                 1
2019-06-05   morning    2                 2
2019-06-05   morning    2                 3

2019-06-05   morning    3                 1
2019-06-05   morning    3                 3

2019-06-05   evening    1                 1
2019-06-05   evening    1                 2

2019-06-05   evening    2                 1
2019-06-05   evening    2                 2
2019-06-05   evening    2                 3
```

There are some subgroups per "date", "date_time" and "day_time_counter" (which I separated them with a blank line to make them more visible).
Each sub group can have one, two or three "area".

What I want is to filter the df in order to get only one subgroup per "date" and "day_time" which has the largest "day_time_counter" AND contain the 3 different "area" values (1, 2, 3), i.e. the selected subgroups should contain 3 rows, one per "area" value.

Meaning, after filtering the df above, I should get as OUTPUT:

```
date         day_time   day_time_counter  area

2019-06-05   morning    2                 1
2019-06-05   morning    2                 2
2019-06-05   morning    2                 3

2019-06-05   evening    2                 1
2019-06-05   evening    2                 2
2019-06-05   evening    2                 3
```

So far I only managed to filter by getting the subgroup with the largest "day_time_counter" but I do not know how to include the condition of being a complete subgroup with the 3 "area".

```
df_new = df.sort_values('day_time_counter', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(['area', 'date', 'day_time'])
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will produce what you're looking for:

```py
area_grp_cols = ["date", "day_time", "day_time_counter"]
counter_grp_cols = ["date", "day_time"]
result = (
    df.assign(area_count=lambda df: df.groupby(area_grp_cols)['area']
                                      .transform("count"))
      .loc[lambda df: df["area_count"] == 3]
      .drop(columns=["area_count"])
      .loc[lambda df: df["day_time_counter"]
                      == df.groupby(counter_grp_cols)["day_time_counter"]
                           .transform("max")]
)
```

Output:

```
          date day_time  day_time_counter  area
3   2019-06-05  morning                 2     1
4   2019-06-05  morning                 2     2
5   2019-06-05  morning                 2     3
10  2019-06-05  evening                 2     1
11  2019-06-05  evening                 2     2
12  2019-06-05  evening                 2     3
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves it! And is not as horrible as I though it would be :)

Answer (score 0):

i think your wanted output should be different (evening have day time 3)
so i think my code is correct:

choseing the max that has all 3 areas:

```
m = df.groupby(['date', 'day_time', 'day_time_counter']).area
new_df = []
for k , _ in m:
    if len(set( _ )) != 3:
        continue
    new_df.append(df[(df.date == k[0]) & (df.day_time == k[1]) & (df.day_time_counter == k[2])])
new_df = pd.concat(new_df, join='outer')
```

filtering the max daytimes :

```
g = new_df.groupby(['date', 'day_time'])
g.filter(lambda x: len(set(x.area)) == 3)
g = g.day_time_counter.max()
```

and wrapping up:

```
itr = [df[(df.date == idx[0]) & (df.day_time == idx[1]) & (df.day_time_counter == value)] for idx, value in zip(g.index, g)]
new_df = pd.concat(itr, join='outer')
new_df
```

tell me if this is what you wanted

Comment: No because that would not take into account that there might be a subgroup with less than 3 "area" but which is still the max with respect to "day_time_counter". I should get what I have shown as the output.

Comment: then df[df.area == 3].groupby(['area', 'date', 'day_time']).max()

Comment: I mean the 3 different possible "area" values (1,2,3), no that area=3. I will try to make my question more clear, but it is not straight forward.

Comment: you can as many conditions you want , i did not understand the output you wish, you can do the following: 
 df[(df.area == 3) & (more conditions) & (more conditons)].groupby(['area', 'date', 'day_time']).max()

Comment: Hi, I edited to show the df's as tables, maybe it is more clear like that. I do not want to filter for a specific area number, I do want the subgroups which contain the three rows of the three different "area" values.

Comment: Hi, I ran your code and it says `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'index'`. The code seems too convoluted, not sure if it is the best approach. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

```
df['group'] = df['area'].eq(1).cumsum()

df_out = df.groupby(['date','day_time','group'])[['area','day_time_counter']]\
           .agg({'area':lambda x: x.nunique()==3,'day_time_counter':'sum'})

df_out.loc[df_out['area'], 'day_time_counter']\
      .rank(ascending=False, method='dense').eq(1).loc[lambda x: x]\
      .to_frame()\
      .merge(df, on=['date','day_time','group'], suffixes=('_',''))[df.columns]
```

Output:

```
   area        date day_time  day_time_counter  group
0     1  2019-06-05  evening                 2      5
1     2  2019-06-05  evening                 2      5
2     3  2019-06-05  evening                 2      5
3     1  2019-06-05  morning                 2      2
4     2  2019-06-05  morning                 2      2
5     3  2019-06-05  morning                 2      2
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but that gives a completely different output of what is needed.

Comment: What output is needed?

Comment: I included as a table in the question.

Comment: Hi, looks like it nows solves the problem. Thanks a lot. However I chose the another answer because it is more compact and straightforward.